# ASP.NET Web Api url design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I try to use Web Api in an ASP.NET MVC4 application.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionIdApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "ActionApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );   
        }
    }

    public class OrganisationApiController : ApiController
    {
        public List<Direction> GetDirections()
        {
            List<Direction> res = new List<Direction>();
            using (SerializerContext context = new SerializerContext())
            {
                res = context.DirectionSet.ToList();
            }
            return res;
        }

        public List<Departement> GetDepartements(int directionId)
        {
            List<Departement> res = new List<Departement>();
            using (SerializerContext context = new SerializerContext())
            {
                res = context.DepartementSet.Where(d => d.IdDirection == directionId).ToList();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Application starts with

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {           
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

When I develop I can call all my methods from OrganisationApiController :
`http://localhost:5000/api/OrganisationApi` => GetDirections is called
`http://localhost:5000/api/OrganisationApi/GetDirections` => GetDirections is called
`http://localhost:5000/api/OrganisationApi/GetDepartements/1` => GetDepartement is called with directionId = 1

But when I deploy on a server with IIS
`http://myserver.com:5000/api/OrganisationApi` => GetDirections is called
`http://myserver.com:5000/api/OrganisationApi/GetDirections` => GetDirections is called
`http://myserver.com:5000/api/OrganisationApi/GetDepartements/1` => 404 error

What I am missing?

Comment: If you're using Web API 2, take a look at the new and shiny attribute routings. You can do stuff like denote your controller with `[RoutePrefix("api/organization")]`, and then denote your actions with `[Route("")]` (for the path to be simply `api/organization`) or `[Route("{id}"]` etc.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot use Web Api 2 !

Comment: Check out [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/#asp-net-web-api) package, you should be able to use that with WebApi 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with those routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ActionIdApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "ActionApi",
                  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

The second route is unnecessary (because the first one already handles those requests - id is specified as optional) and it has an error that you specifying that id is optional but the route doesn't contain an id at all.

Either remove the second route and change your action so it receive an optional parameter or replace them with:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ActionIdApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "ActionApi",
                  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                );
```

By the way your default rote is also very problematic because you are not specifying default controller and action - it supposed to be **DEFAULT** right...

From what i see here all your routes could be replaced with this one

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "ApiDefault",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        new { controller = "HomeApi", action="IndexApi" id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Just replace your default values for controller and action.

**EDIT:**

The problem is in your action:

If you specify in your Route "id" parameter your action should be:

```
public List<Departement> GetDepartements(int id)
```

**Parameter names must match.**

Also you can combine both your actions into one action:

```
public List<Departement> GetDepartements(int? id)
        {
            List<Departement> res = new List<Departement>();
            using (SerializerContext context = new SerializerContext())
            {
                if(id.HasValue)
                {
                    res = context.DepartementSet.Where(d => d.IdDirection == directionId).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    res = context.DirectionSet.ToList();
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: I changed WebApi routes but the problem is still there :
- OK on localhost
- KO on a distant server when there is a parameter on request